# What are the scriptures of Tantra that explicitly deals with the (all) devi forms of ma Saraswathi?

Tags: scripture, tantra, saraswati

Although I do not know all the forms of Saraswathi that are explained in the Scriptures, I heard about Swetha Saraswathi, Neela Saraswathi, and some others. Each such devi has a visual form, mantra, and tantra upasana.

I think that these forms are cryptic/implicit in well-known scriptures such as puranas,  ithihasas, etc., but are explicit in the scriptures of Tantra.

I know that every such form has an associated mantra, which generally has to get initiated by a Sidda guru. In which scriptures of tantra, forms of Saraswathi are mentioned along with other associated information such as mantras?

Is there a single scripture that enumerated all the forms of Saraswathi or are they mentioned across several scriptures?

Answer (score 0):

I know, you are asking about tantra but my answer is from Upanishad as in the tag portion, scripture is also added.

The Shandilya Upanishad of Atharvana Veda describes Maa Saraswati as the tridevis and also the pranava AUM, mentions the below.:

> *Sitting in the paḍma posture, the person should meditate that there is at the tip of his nose **Gāyaṭrī,** a girl of **red complexion** surrounded by the numberless rays of the image of the moon and mounted on a hamsa (swan) and having a mace in her hand. She is the visible symbol of the letter A. The letter U has as its visible symbol **Sāviṭrī,** a young woman of **white colour** having a disk in her hand and riding on a garuda (eagle). The letter M has as its visible symbol **Sarasvaṭī,** an aged woman of **black/blue colour** riding on a bull, having a trident in her hand.*

I hope this clarifies your queries.